# DatePicker border issue causes deposition of all other controls

Tags: c#, wpf, datepicker

I'm using C# to code a UWP app including some views with DatePicker controls.

As I changed the style of those DatePicker controls and tried to design them like some other controls (Textboxes, Textblocks,...) there were some issues with the Borders of the DatePickers.

I don't want any Border when the DatePickers have the VisualState "Normal" but want a Border at the VisualStates "PointerOver", "Pressed", ... I already set the BorderThickness to "0" at the "Normal" State, but when I have another State than "Normal" in the executed App, all my controls beneath the DatePickers move down slightly which doesn't look good for me.

Ideally the Border should appear for the DatePicker but not on the "Normal" VisualState and the other Controls should keep there given positions.

Comment: what about changing the border color to the background color in normal state instead of setting its thickness to 0? this workaround would prevent the control from resizing

Comment: Works perfectly, thanks!